# ASP.NET MVC the user account created in ASP.NET configuration unusable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm new to asp.net MVC.

I'm using VWD Express 2012，ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application template, Razor engine to develop my web application.

This is the problem I'm having:

After enable and created role(Administrator) and user account in Project -ASP.NET configuration. I couldn't log in with the account I just created. The error message is "The user name or password provided is incorrect." However in the tutorial, MvcMusicStore(http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-7) I followed their steps and successfully created Administrator account. Therefore, I couldn't find out what caused that problem.

But the account I created by Ctrl + F5 - "Register" on the top left is able to log in.

Thanks for your time reading this post.
Any hints or website links are appreciated.

Comment: Did you by any chance deploy your application to a server and then created the account on your local PC?

Comment: Does ASP.NET Development Server counts? Cuz I'm in the testing phase so I only use Ctrl+F5 to run the application and monitor the changes I made. I mean I only run it locally if that's what you were asking.

Comment: No, if it's local you should be OK. The only thing I can imagine is that your ASP.NET configuration tool is writing the data to a different database then the one your application is reading from. Could you check your web.config and your application to make sure they both are targetting the same DB?

Comment: Sure, I'll do it right away, thanks for the hints:)

Comment: BTW how many <connectionStrings> can I have in the web.config? Cuz I added one <connectionStrings> other than the defaultConnection. Can this be the cause of my problem?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Just to check, delete all but one ConnectionString and try the same thing again (adding a user in the config-tool and then logging into the app with that one)

Comment: Fort testing that I created a new project, using ASP.NET 4 Web Application, Internet Application template. Then go to PROJECT - ASP.NET Configuration, created one role and an user account that assigned with that role. After that I close the Configuration tab, and run the application. Clicked "Log in" and trying to log in with the username I just created. It is said "The user name or password provided is incorrect."

Comment: I checked the Data Connections in the Database Explorer there are two connections are created inside "aspnet-UerTesting-20130924215458.mdf" and "DefaultConnection (UerTesting)". Both of them contents the same 5 tables "UserProfile", "webpages_Membership", "webpages_OAuthMembership", "webpages_Roles" and "webpages_UsersInRoles". When I check them with "show table data", they are all empty. However, when I go to ASP.NET Configuration the Role and user account I created earlier are still there. So where is the role and user account data in Configuration are stored? I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the comments, I can see what's happening.

Your MVC app is using the SimpleMembershipProvider. This provider is not compatible with the configuration tool. The config tool uses different tables and is thus not compatible.

You can do one of two things in this case:
- don't use the configuration tool but use a script, or maybe create your own admin pages.
- Disable simple membership so that MVC uses the old membership system

As for the database, you'll notice that after using the config tool, the tool creates a .MDF-file under the App_Data directory, that's where your user is stored that you created with the tool

Comment: Thank you so much. After reading your answer I start to understand what is happening. About your first suggestion, writing my own script, if you got some useful links(tutorial) that might helps me learning how to do it? I'll also do my own research. Thanks again:)